# Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^x = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

We define $e^x$ as the inverse of $\ln(x)$, and we want to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^x = \infty$.

I'm trying to argue that since $\ln(x)$ is surjective, then $\forall x$ $\exists t$ ($t>0$) such that $\ln(t) = x$. As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $\ln(t) \rightarrow \infty$, that means $t \rightarrow \infty$ since $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \ln(t) = \infty$ and $\ln$ is strictly increasing (this step is intuitively correct but I feel like it's not rigorous enough, can I actually say that?), and thus $\exp(x) = \exp(\ln(t)) = t \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: indeed $\ln(.)$ is increasing

Comment: Try Taylor series, then you can solve it with basic mathematical analysis technique.

Comment: You could prove $\ln(t)$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$  then carry on. We could also prove $x < e^x$ and then get it more directly from that.

Comment: Or you can also use the fact that $e^x > x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and hence the result follows.

Comment: How is $\ln x$ defined? As an integral?

Comment: By definition, an expression of the form “$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$” means the following: $\forall M>0\, \exists x_0\, \forall x\, (x \geq x_0 \implies  f(x) \geq M)$. So, in the case that $f$ is the exponential function, given $M>0$ set $x_0 := \ln(M)$ and note that $\forall x\, (x \geq x_0 \implies  f(x) \geq M)$.

Answer (score 1):

$ln$ is a strictly increasing bijection (clearly because its derivative which is by definition : $\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly positive), so its reciprocal is also strictly increasing . This is the argument you were missing .